# Read Google App Script Files from another script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am looking to create a little Google App Script to parse another GAS file to pull out the functions and any jsdoc type comments, and then display it.
Like if you navigate to a script you can get the revision history etc, but I wanted to be able to pass in a Drive folder containing multiple script files and develop a front end to display each's content.

I know about the Google Drive REST API with `exportLinks` do download as JSON.
I wondered if there was a simpler way to do it from another GAS file, or would I need to URLFetch of some description to do it over the RestAPI?

I have tried searching for similar things but they always lead back to the DriveAPI.

Any help with a starting place, or what GAS Objects I should start looking at?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the REST based Drive API, there is really no other alternative. However, you don't need to use URLFetch to access it. Google Apps Script has what's known as [Advance Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) a collection of interfaces that grant native access to many REST based APIS including the Drive API.

You can check out the Drive specific documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive). Its somewhat sparse, so you'll often have to fall back on the [REST based documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/) as well as rely on autocomplete inside the script editor to make sense of things.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much
Hadn't seen the advanced services, very interesting, thanks!